# adding values to unknown element ids in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created form in that a user can click "add row" and get a new element in the form.

some of the elements are quantity and price.  I want to change values based on what users enter.  so if he chooses qty=4 and price=10 i want amount to =40.

I dont know what to use as the selector for price or amount since input ids are dynamically generated.

```
var form = "<tr><td>Quantity</td>
                <td><input class='qty' type='text' id='qty[]' name='qty[]'></td>";

    form += "<td>Part Num</td>
             <td><input type='text' id='part[]' name='part[]'></td>";

    form += "<td>Description</td>
             <td><input class='desc' type='text' id='desc[]' name='desc[]'></td>";

    form += "<td>Unit Price</td>
             <td><input type='text' id='price[]' name='price[]'></td>";

    form += "<td>Amount</td>
             <td><input type='text' id='amount[]' name='amount'></td></tr>";

            $('#addItem').click(function(){
                    $('#itemsTable').append(form);
            });


     $(document).on('change','.qty',function(){

          //What can i use as a selector for value_of_qty and value_of_price here???

          //var total = $(value_of_qty) * $(value_of_price);
          //$(id_of_amount).val(total);
      });
```

on form submissions i see the following:

```
[qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => asdfdasf
        [1] => asdfdasf
    )
and so on....
```

Comment: It looks to me like you've closured around the `form` variable, which contains the HTML you'd like to dynamically append to the `#itemsTable` element when the user clicks on `#addItem`. There's no indication that you dynamically change that HTML at any point in this process. So _all_ added rows will end up having the exact same `id` attribute values for their `input` elements, which is not allowed, as all `id` attribute values on a page must be unique. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well as a test, i had a submit button to see what it would see what form sent.  it shows an array for each field (qty array('0'='x','1'='y')...and so on...

Comment: I assume you're using PHP server-side which is interpreting the brackets in the form element `name`s according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137557/using-square-brackets-in-hidden-html-input-fields. That PHP trick does _not_ apply to `id`s; it just looks at the `name` values. I'm pretty sure your HTML is invalid because you have duplicate `id`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I described in my comment, your HTML is invalid because you have duplicate `id`s. You should dynamically generate the HTML you append to the parent element, and assign a unique `id` value with each appendage. Here's what I would do:

```
var g_ROWNUM = 1;

$('#addItem').click(function() {

    var form = '\
        <tr>\
            <td>Quantity</td><td><input class="qty" type="text" id="qty_${num}" name="qty[]"></td>\
            <td>Part Num</td><td><input type="text" id="part_${num}" name="part[]"></td>\
            <td>Description</td><td><input class="desc" type="text" id="desc_${num}" name="desc[]"></td>\
            <td>Unit Price</td><td><input type="text" id="price_${num}" name="price[]"></td>\
            <td>Amount</td><td><input type="text" id="amount_${num}" name="amount[]"></td>\
        </tr>\
    '.replace(/\$\{num\}/g,g_ROWNUM++);

    $('#itemsTable').append(form);

});

$(document).on('change', '.qty', function() {

    var qtyInput = $(this);
    var num = qtyInput.attr('id').replace(/^qty_/,'');
    var priceInput = $('#price_'+num);
    var amountInput = $('#amount_'+num);

    var total = qtyInput.val()*priceInput.val();
    amountInput.val(total);

});
```

As you can see, this allows you to extract the generated number and use it to retrieve the price and amount elements in the same row as the changed quantity element, and then apply any dynamic changes you want to the elements in that row.

http://jsfiddle.net/p6wrkne4/1/

Answer (score 2):

You have (roughly) this structure:

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="qty"></td>
  <td><input name="price[]"></td>
</tr>
```

So, given that you have the `.qty` input, all you need to do is rise to the `tr` and get its `input[name='price[]']`. In code:

```
$(document).on('change','.qty',function(){
  var $qty = $(this);
  var $price = $qty.closest("tr").find("input[name='price[]']");
});
```

Comment: Why `$qty` and `$price` instead of `qty` and `price`?

Comment: Just a convention I use

Answer (score 0):

you should restructure your html by adding classes like this:

```
<tr class="tableRow">
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td><input class='qty' type='text' id='qty[]' name='qty[]'/></td><td>Part Num</td>
    <td><input type='text' id='part[]' name='part[]'/></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><input class='desc' type='text' id='desc[]' name='desc[]'/></td>
    <td>Unit Price</td>
    <td><input type='text' class="price" id='price[]' name='price[]'/></td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td><input type='text' class="amount" id='amount[]' name='amount'/></td>
</tr>

$(document).on('change', '.qty', function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).closest('.tableRow').find('.price').val();
    var total = qty * price;
    $(this).closest('.tableRow').find('.amount').val(total);
});
```

Comment: the rest of whatever i want to do is the question.  i want to put this value times the price field value in the amount field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).on('change','.qty',function(){
   var qtyInput = $(this);
   var price = qtyInput.closest("tr").find("input[name='price[]']").val();
   var amount = qtyInput.val() * price;        
   qtyInput.closest("tr").find("input[name=amount]").val(amount);
});
```