# How to save data from dynamic generated radio-buttons and input-fields to a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am developing a webpage with dynamically generated input-fields and radio-buttons. Becuase of this each ID to the radio-buttons and input-fields is also generated dynamically.

The website is meant to be a school test application. This part of the website is where the teacher may create a test where each question has four alternatives, one which one of them is correct. Each test is meant to be sent to many different persons. And of course, the test application can be used to create tests with many different titles. When a test is saved to a database, it must be possible to collect all data from these tests.

1- How do I collect the data of the input-fields?
2- How do I show which radio-button and ìts paired input-field that was selected
3- How do I maintain the relationship between the different values? 
4- how do I save the data to a MySQL database?

The title, the questions, the answers and which of these is the correct way. Because of this, the generation of the different test-ids is rather complicated and follows a certain pattern:

All test-titles has the ID: "theTitle"

**Each question has an ID that has this particular pattern:**

```
theTitle + "Q" + name
```

Q for "question"

name is a numeric value: The first question has number one and so on.
Example: *JavaQ1*

**Each ID of the four radio buttons has this pattern:**

```
theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "1"
```

O for Option
"1" can be 1 to four.
Example *JavaQ5O4*

**Each ID of the for input-fields that is paired with the radio-buttons has this pattern:**

```
theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "1"
```

Example: *JavaQ4input4*

**And each radio-button has also a name to distinguish them from other groups of radio-buttons. These names follow this pattern:**

```
theTitle + "rb" + name
```

rb for radiobutton

Example: *Java10rb4*

**JavaScript:**       [JsFiddle: Here you can see the application in action](https://jsfiddle.net/d9tfk1u6/59/)!

```
   $("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function () {
    name++;
    $(".dynamicform").append(createQuestion(name));

});


$(".dynamicform").append(createQuestion(name));
function createQuestion(name){
    var dynamic=`<span class="module">
                    <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-10"></legend>
                    <div class="input-group input-group">
                        <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                         <!-- The Question Inputfield that needs ID-->

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name}" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;"
                                   for="wQuestion">Enter
                                avaible options:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <!-- The radiobuttons and option inputfields that needs ID's-->

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" value="1"  name="${theTitle +"rb"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "1"}" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "1"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" value="2" name="${theTitle +"rb"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "2"}" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "2"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" value="3" name="${theTitle +"rb"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "3"}" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "3"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" value="4" name="${theTitle +"rb"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "4"}" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "4"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                `;
    return dynamic;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to save data from the dynamic input-fields and radio-buttons. I used two for-loops to first get access to the different ids. Then their values are saved to different variables that may be saved into a database:

```
    $("#saveTest").click(function () {        

        for (var i = 1; i <= name; i++) {
            var questionId  = theTitle + "Q" + name;

            //The Question
            var question = $("#" + questionId).val();

            for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {

              // The IDs of the radio-buttons and the inputfields:
                var radioBtnID = theTitle + "Q" + [i] + "O" + [j];
                var inputTextId = theTitle + "Q" + [i] + "input" + [j];

            // Text from all the different input-fields
                var inputText = $("#" + inputTextId).val();

              // The right alternative (that is selected with radio-button)
                if($("#"+ radioBtnID).is(':checked')) {

                    console.log("The right answer: " +inputText+ " Right answer: " + inputTextId);
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need include a value for each radio button too.

Right now your code look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="onlinerg1" id="onlineQ1O1" aria-label="">
```

should also include `Value=1` to `Value=4` so you can different between each option and save the option text on the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a little bit differently.

The `id` attribute attached to your form inputs does not really matter when you submit a form, what matters is the `name` attribute as that is what gets submitted with its corresponding value.

How you name your inputs might benefit you on the server-side when you need to retrieve the values. In PHP, when you submit inputs with the [array notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137557/using-square-brackets-in-hidden-html-input-fields), you can retrieve them as an array or multi-dimensional array as we are about to do.

Give a common `name` attribute to every input e.q. `qs`. Relate them by appending `[index][field]`. For example, `qs[0][question]` is the first question's text, `qs[0][alt][0]` is the first question's first alternative, `qs[2][answer]` is the third question's answer.

**JS**

```
// use document.ready not window.onload
$(function() {
    var name = 0; // start questions with index 0

    $("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function () {
        $(".dynamicform").append(createQuestion(name++)); // shorter
    });

    $(".dynamicform").append(createQuestion(name++));

    function createQuestion(name){
        // replace id with name attributes
        var dynamic=`<span class="module">
                        <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-10"></legend>
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" name="${"qs[" + name + "][question]"}" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;"
                                       for="wQuestion">Enter
                                    avaible options:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <!-- The radiobuttons and option inputfields that needs ID's-->

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <input type="radio" value="0" name="${"qs[" + name + "][answer]"}" aria-label="">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="${"qs[" + name + "][alt][0]"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <input type="radio" value="1" name="${"qs[" + name + "][answer]"}" aria-label="">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="${"qs[" + name + "][alt][1]"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <input type="radio" value="2" name="${"qs[" + name + "][answer]"}" aria-label="">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="${"qs[" + name + "][alt][2]"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <input type="radio" value="3" name="${"qs[" + name + "][answer]"}" aria-label="">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="${"qs[" + name + "][alt][3]"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    `;
        return dynamic;
    }
});
```

**PHP (example)**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $qs = !empty($_POST['qs']) ? $_POST['qs'] : [];
    // loop through questions
    foreach ($qs as $i => $q) {
        $question = $q['question'];
        $alts = $q['alt'];
        // radio buttons do not get submitted if they are not selected
        $answer = isset($q['answer']) ? $q['answer'] : null;

        printf('Question %d: %s<br>', $i + 1, $question);

        // loop through question's alternatives
        foreach ($alts as $j => $alt) {
            printf('Alternative %d: %s<br>', $j + 1, $alt); 
        }

        if (isset($alts[$answer])) {
            printf('Answer: %s<br>', $alts[$answer]);
        }
    }

    //echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
}
```